# Read AMQP message headers spring cloud stream

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-amqp

I made spring batch application that produces amqp (rabbitmq) messages which consists of list of json objects. Messages have headers with some metadata. Spring cloud stream app is consuming messages, and I used functional approach. How can I access the headers?
Is it bad approach to use message headers for anything but routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function signature in Spring Cloud Stream application accepts Message (for example):

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Message<?>> consume() {
    return message -> {
        message.getHeaders()....
    };
}
```

. .  then you can simply access message headers.
We're also working on simplifying it a bit.

No, it s not *a bad approach to use message headers for anything but routing*.
Think of Message Headers as meta information, only relevant to the current message . . . anything that is important for the current message but not after.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I suspected that it was a bad idea, because I couldn't easily find a way to access said headers. And that was my reasoning, meta info could come via headers.